# how to display more than 1 image on google colab

Tags: python

how to display more than 1 image on google colab

```
from google.colab import files
from keras.preprocessing import image

uploaded = files.upload()
for fn in uploaded.keys():
  path = fn
  img = image.load_img(path, target_size=(150,150))
```

I've tried this script but it doesn't work

Comment: This do not display image but upload it to your folders.

Comment: I try to upload 3 image using uploaded = files.upload(), but when i show image with imgplot = plt.imshow(img), only 1 image show

Comment: this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48435229/how-to-plot-a-list-of-image-in-loop-using-matplotlib . you can use subplot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to plot a list of image in loop using matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48435229/how-to-plot-a-list-of-image-in-loop-using-matplotlib)

Comment: how to use it with uploaded.files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you to display in each line then put `plt.show()` below the `plt.imshow()`

If you want to display in form like grid then use `subplot`

It will be like this(will display in a single row):

```
from google.colab import files
from keras.preprocessing import image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

uploaded = files.upload()
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
for num, fn in enumerate(uploaded.keys()):
  path = fn
  img = image.load_img(path, target_size=(150,150))
  plt.subplot(1,len(uploaded),num+1) # <-------
  plt.axis('off')
  plt.imshow(img)
```

Or

```
for fn in uploaded.keys():
  fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
  path = fn
  img = image.load_img(path, target_size=(150,150))
  plt.axis('off')
  plt.imshow(img)
  plt.show() #<------------here
```